# Let S be the set of positive integers expressed as $x^2 +dy^2$, prove that if $a, b \in S$, then $ab \in S$

Tags: number-theory

Let $d$ be a positive integer, and let $S$ be the set of all positive integers of the form $x^2 + dy^2$, where $x$ and $y$ are non-negative integers.

> (a) Prove that if $a ∈ S$ and $b ∈ S$, then $ab ∈ S$.

I tried expanding, letting $a = {x^2_1 + dy^2_1}$ and $a = {x^2_2 + dy^2_2}$ in which nothing happened. After this, I tried using small numbers like $d = 5$, to see if I could find a pattern. Unfortunately, it seemed like the Squares that I have computed are random (I couldn't find anything). I'm not sure what technique to use.

Problem from https://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/SatoNT.pdf

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Note that $x^2 + dy^2 = (x + \sqrt{-d} y)(x - \sqrt{-d} y)$. (If you're not comfortable with complex numbers, this is true at least formally.)

Now expand $(x_1 + \sqrt{-d} y_1)(x_2 + \sqrt{-d} y_2)$.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that the set of sums of two squares is closed by multiplication. Using one of the two identities showing this we get
$$(x^2+(\sqrt d y)^2)(z^2+(\sqrt d w)^2)=(xz+dyw)^2+(xw-yz)^2d$$ which gives the identity showing the product $(x^2+dy^2)(z^2+dw^2)$ is an element of $S$.